# setting up and choosing which gallery to flip through its images

Tags: python, image, pygame, imaging

i was trying to choose with keyboard input 1 and 2 to choose the gallery 1 or 2 which is a list of images to be loaded on the screen
it worked fine with one gallery with this code

```
import pygame


WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Needed to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
# Put the images into a list.
images = [
    pygame.image.load('assets/download.png').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/mickey.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/cat.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/flavours.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/hallway.jpg').convert(),
    ]
image_index = 0
image = images[image_index]  # The current image.

x = 0  # x coordnate of image
y = 0  # y coordinate of image

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                image_index -= 1  # Decrement the index.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                image_index += 1  # Increment the index.

            # Keep the index in the valid range.
            image_index %= len(images)
            # Switch the image.
            image = images[image_index]

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Blit the current image.
    screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 fps.

pygame.quit()
```

but trying to add more lists and to be picked just didnt work. i tried making the choice of gallery in a different loop and under the same loop and nothing is working.

```
import pygame


WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Needed to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
# Put the images into a list.
gallery1 = [
    pygame.image.load('assets/download.png').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/mickey.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/cat.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/flavours.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/hallway.jpg').convert(),
    ]

gallery2 = [
    pygame.image.load('assets/adv.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/star.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/images.jpeg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/tile.png').convert(),
    ]

x = 0  # x coordnate of image
y = 0  # y coordinate of image

running = True
gallery = gallery1 #set the default gallery

image_index = 0
image = gallery[image_index]  # The current image.

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                gallery = gallery1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                gallery = gallery2            
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                image_index -= 1  # Decrement the index.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                image_index += 1  # Increment the index.

            # Keep the index in the valid range.
            image_index %= len(gallery)
            # Switch the image.
            image = gallery[image_index]

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Blit the current image.
    screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 fps.

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working finally after i posted the problem
i would be glad to see any hints or ideas to improve how this program works.

```
import pygame


WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Needed to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
# Put the images into a list.
gallery1 = [
    pygame.image.load('assets/download.png').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/mickey.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/cat.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/flavours.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/hallway.jpg').convert(),
    ]

gallery2 = [
    pygame.image.load('assets/adv.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/star.jpg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/images.jpeg').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('assets/tile.png').convert(),
    ]

x = 0  # x coordnate of image
y = 0  # y coordinate of image

running = True
gallery = gallery1 #set the default gallery

image_index = 0
image = gallery[image_index]  # The current image.

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                gallery = gallery1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                gallery = gallery2                      
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                image_index -= 1  # Decrement the index.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                image_index += 1  # Increment the index.

            # Keep the index in the valid range.
            image_index %= len(gallery)
            # Switch the image.
            image = gallery[image_index]

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Blit the current image.
    screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 fps.

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Thank you,  now im thinking can I flip through galleries with the other arrow keys?

Comment: Sure. You could put the gallery lists into a list of lists and use another index variable to get the current list.

Comment: please clarify how can i make this list of lists

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this comment, but I think I meant a list of galleries like this: `galleries = [gallery1, gallery2]` and then access the current gallery with an index variable: `gallery = galleries[1]`.